# Can the Lovecraftian mythos be found in our modern world?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft

How solidly anchored are the Lovecraft stories of Cthulhu, Arkham, Miskatonic University in the early 20th century? Have there been any significant efforts to update the mythos, with stories, to an early 21st century setting? If so, how well has the idea of a "Cthulhu Now" caught on with the fans?

Comment: Check out the comic Providence by Alan Moore and Jacen Burrows.

Comment: I know it's set in 1919, but it's pretty amazing.

Comment: Maybe this question could be reworded to make it less of a "list" request?

Comment: You might like Elizabeth Bear's excellent novelette [*Shoggoths in Bloom.*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoggoths_in_Bloom)

Comment: I've tried to make it a bit less "listy", I am not sure how well it succeeded...

Comment: People still write Myhos stories.  There is a book series called "Black Wings of Cthulhu" (currently up to Volume 4) of short stories.  Some are set in modern day; some are not.  There are other collections listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu_Mythos_anthology)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Charles Stross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Stross) has a [series of stories that assume that certain mathematics and algorithms are magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Stross#The_Laundry_Files) and give access to occult tools including things similar to Lovecratian horrors.

The British government agency in charge of these matters is ["The Laundry"](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2016/04/faq-the-laundry-filesseries-ti.html) and gives its nickname to the setting and stories.

Comment: Definitely +1 on this! And what excellent fun romps they are! Though the Lovecraftian horrors frequently pale in comparison to the horrors of TPS reports, government acquisition procedures, KPIs and hard/software so outdated it makes Windows 95 look modern!